# CFSwapInt32LittleToHost equivalent in java

Tags: java, c

I am trying to write the below code in java. CFSwapInt32LittleToHost here tries to convert or order the bytes from Little Endian to Host byte order. Can someone tell me is there any equivalent java function or suggest me how to write this in java.

```
//  All temperatures are read in celsius.
        //  For display in Farenheit, manual conversion is required.
        NSData *data = characteristic.value;
        uint8_t* dataPointer = (uint8_t*)[data bytes];

        uint8_t flags = dataPointer[0]; dataPointer++;
        int32_t tempData = (int32_t)CFSwapInt32LittleToHost(*(uint32_t*)dataPointer); dataPointer += 4;
        int8_t exponent = (int8_t)(tempData >> 24);
        int32_t mantissa = (int32_t)(tempData & 0x00FFFFFF);

        if( tempData == 0x007FFFFF )
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid temperature value received");
            return;
        }

        float tempValue = (float)(mantissa*pow(10, exponent));

        [_delegate updateTemperature:tempValue];
```

Comment: Do you need function for CFSwapInt32LittleToHost ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I recommend that you solve this problem in Java is the same in C: You need to recognise the distinction between *internal endianness* and *over-the-wire endianness*, and try to avoid producing *internal endianness*.

If you have a sequence of bytes, and you wish to combine them to form an integer value, use multiplication and addition in whichever order the *over-the-wire* endianness specifies that you should do so. That's how you do it without producing *internal endianness*.

If, for whatever reason aside from producing *internal endianness*, you really do need to *swap endianness*, you can do that by rearranging the bytes. The algorithm will be the same going from "little endian" to "big endian" as it is from "big endian" to "little endian", so it probably shouldn't be called something like `CFSwapInt32LittleToHost`; it should be called `swap_endian`.